# modal keep open during validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I'm doing a record with a modal boostrap laravel performing validation. sending data via jquery ajax realize it. the problem I have is that pressing the submit button closes the modal. how you could do to keep open modal until the end of the validacion ?? Thank you

modal:

```
 <!--- Register Modal -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="Register" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Registro</h4>
          </div>
           <div class="modal-body">


           <form class="form" role="form" id="new-user" data-token="{{ Session::token() }}" method="post" >
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

               <div id="error">
                   <!-- error will be showen here ! -->
               </div>

                  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="name">Nombre completo: </label>
                       <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                    </div>


                 <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="email">Correo electronico: </label>
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                     <label for="pwd">Contraseña:</label>
                     <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                 </div>

                   <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label >Confirmar contraseña:</label>
                        <input id="cpassword" type="password" class="form-control" name="cpassword">

                                @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                   </div>

               <!-- <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}"> seguridad -->
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="Submit" >Registro</button>

                <div>
        <!-- boton login facebook-->
         <div>
            <a href="/login-facebook" class="login-facebook" </div><span data-reactid=".1.0.1.2.1:0">Facebook</span></a>
          </div>

        <!-- boton login google-->
           <div>
            <a href="/login-google" class="login-google" </div><span data-reactid="">Google</span></a>
          </div>
          </div>



        </form>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

js:

```
function send(event){
    event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            type: 'post',
            url: "{{url('/register')}}",
            data: {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                password: $('#password').val(),
                cpassword: $('#cpassword').val(),
                _token: $('#new-user').attr('data-token')
            },
             success: function (data) {
                  $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function () {

                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; ' + data + ' !</div>');

                });

               }

        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would Just give you an easy Validation Example. You can use it your own way
and to hide the modal Just add `$("#Your Modal ID ").modal("hide");` if your Modal `ID` is Register then Use `$("#Register").modal("hide");` and it will close

```
function send(event){
    event.preventDefault();

   if((!$('#name').val())||(!$('#email').val())||(!$('#password').val()))
   {
    alert("Please Fill All The Details !")
    }
else{

        $.ajax({

            type: 'post',
            url: "{{url('/register')}}",
            data: {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                password: $('#password').val(),
                cpassword: $('#cpassword').val(),
                _token: $('#new-user').attr('data-token')
            },
             success: function (data) {
                  $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function () {

                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; ' + data + ' !</div>');


                });
                $("#Your Modal ID ").modal("hide");
               }

        });
   }
}
```

Comment: hello, the problem is not validation. what I want is that the modal remains open after pressing submit

Comment: @RecoJhonatan Just add `$("Your Modal ID ").modal("hide");`  if your id is Register then Use `$("#Register").modal("hide");` and it will close

Comment: ajax can be sent by a button-type 'button' instead of a submit?

Comment: @RecoJhonatan : yes , ajax has nothing to do with submit or form ,intput type button will also do the same work for ajax call

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you call the `send()` js function... so I don't know if you are preventing form submission. Anyway:

Your modal should not been closed on submit the form, except if the form is really being sent and your page reloads.

To prevent your form from being submitted and the current page to reload:

```
$('#new-user').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault; });
```

And to close the modal in your ajax.success function try to use:

```
$('#Register').modal('hide');
```